# Why the INSERT query doesn't work in this HttpServer code

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

Im trying to make a little server for my homework.This is very simple project yet i cant insert some variables (which i took from the client ,in an object form ,through serialization ) into the database .
It shows no errors! That's what i find strange and also the client receive the response without problems.

my Server class is as the following :

```
package server;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.ietf.jgss.Oid;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(3333), 0);

    server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(t.getRequestBody());
        final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/httpServer";

        final String user = "root";

        final String password = "";

        try {
            Send oin = (Send) ios.readObject();

            String response = "Kjo eshte nje pergjigje nga serveri! \n"
                    + "Clienti me id "
                    + oin.getId()
                    + " dhe me emer "
                    + oin.getName()
                    + " ka pasur "
                    + oin.getAmount()
                    + "$ ne llogarine e tij ,por me pas ka terhequr "
                    + oin.getPaid()
                    + "$ nga llogaria \n"
                    + "Kjo terheqe eshte ruajtur ne database dhe tani gjendja e re eshte "
                    + (oin.getAmount() - oin.getPaid()) + "$ \n";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
            int id = oin.getId();
            String emri = oin.getName();
            int amount = oin.getAmount();
            int paid = oin.getPaid();
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,
                        password);

                try {
                    Statement s = con.createStatement();

                    s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO person VALUES ('" + id
                            + "','" + emri + "','" + amount + "','" + paid
                            + "')");
                } catch (SQLException s) {

                    System.out
                            .println("Tabel or column or data type is not found!");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
   }
```

can you please help me ?
Or have any idea what the problem may is ?

Edit:
Maybe i am doing something wrong in the Client:

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;

class Send implements Serializable {
// duhet te implementoje interfacin serizable ne menyre qe tja dergoj
// serverit
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public int getPaid() {
    return paid;
}

int id = 1;
int amount = 2000;
int paid = 800;
String name = "Andi Domi";

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
    }

   public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:3333");
        HttpURLConnection s = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        s.setDoOutput(true);
        s.setDoInput(true);
        s.setRequestMethod("POST");
        s.setUseCaches(false);
        Send obj = new Send();
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(
                s.getOutputStream());
        objOut.writeObject(obj);

        InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int c;
        while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) c);
        }
        objOut.close();
        s.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        System.err.print("gabimi eshte ketu");
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: First problem: you're including your values directly in SQL, potentially leading to a SQL injection attack. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Do you have any exception? Try to output exception in `catch (SQLException s)` block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your `executeUpdate` statement you need to do.

```
con.commit();
```

to save the transaction.

**EDIT:** Based on the chat discussion, we learned that the column named `emri` is actually `Emri` in the table and was throwing:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'emri' in 'field list'
```

Changing the name resolves the issue.

---

Now unrelated to your problem, you should be using a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead and should be closing your connection and statement

```
try {
  PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO person(id, emri, amount, paid) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
  s.setInt(1,id);
  s.setString(2,emri);
  s.setInt(3,amount);
  s.setInt(4,paid);
  int count =  s.executeUpdate();
  con.commit();
} catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  //something bad happened rollback 
  //any uncommitted changes
  con.rollback();
} finally {
  if (con != null) {
    con.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: As John just posted, it may have to do with you not supplying the column names in the insert statement.

Comment: connection in autocommit=true mode by default

Comment: sorry to ask but i am a beginner in this field, but in the query "INSERT INTO person(id, emri, amount, paid) VALUES (?,?,?,?)" should i replace the "?" with some values

Comment: Try adding `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch block. Maybe something is throwing an exception and it could point us in the right direction.

Comment: No, you use the `set` methods on the prepared statement to do that. The `?` are essentially indicators that you are going to be passing input to it. It is more secure to do it this way and it escapes things correctly for you. And don't be sorry, we all had to start somewhere.

Comment: ok thank you i do understand now ,yet nothing ! no query effect and no error

Comment: No exception was thrown? Add a `System.out.println("# of Rows Inserted:"+count)` after `int count =  s.executeUpdate();` to see what that value is.

Comment: No exception until ,the Elipse console just show the server output send to the client and that's all

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18863/discussion-between-jschoen-and-p3rand0r)

Comment: Thank you ,everything now work like a charm and this thank to you and the community :)

Answer (score 2):

first, use **[prepared statement<sup>[docs]</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)** to avoid from `SQL INJECTION`

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO person VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
prest.setString(1,id);
prest.setString(2,emri);    // or use setInt for integer
prest.setString(3,amount);  // or use setInt for integer
prest.setString(4,paid);
prest.executeUpdate()
```

second, if the the number of values does not match the total number of columns in your table, it will also fail because you are using the *implicit* type of INSERT statement. To solve it, just supply the column names where you want the values should be stored, eg

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO person (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
```